# is it posible about label animaiton on chart.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I have a hard time for creating bar chart animation on label position. 
bar chart animation is works fine. but the label of the bar doesn't works.

How can I fix this? 
thanks.

```
getChartList(): void {
    this.context = this.barChartDom.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.barChart = new Chart(this.context, {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      data: {
        labels: ['product1', 'product2', 'product3'],
        datasets: [{
          label: "Index",
          backgroundColor: ["#467261","#556e69","#555341"],
          data: [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()]
        }]
      }
    });
    if (this.context) {
      this.context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    }
  }
```

```
 settingChart(barChart: Chart){
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 2000;
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.easing = 'linear';

    Chart.plugins.register({
      beforeUpdate: function(chart) {
        if (chart.options.sort) {
          let dataArray = chart.data.datasets[0].data.slice();
          let dataIndexes = dataArray.map((d, i) => i);
          dataIndexes.sort((a, b) => {
            return dataArray[b] - dataArray[a];
          });

          // sort data array as well
          dataArray.sort((a, b) => a - b);

          let meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
          let newMeta = [];
          let newLabels = [];

          meta.data.forEach((a, i) => {
            newMeta[dataIndexes[i]] = a;
            newLabels[dataIndexes[i]] = chart.data.labels[i];
          });

          meta.data = newMeta;
          chart.data.datasets[0].data = dataArray;
          chart.data.labels = newLabels;

        }
      }
    });
  }
```

bar part part is works fine.

```
  nextchart(){
    this.chartService.getNextBarChartList().pipe().subscribe(rest => { 
      rest.datasets.map((ds, i) => { 
        ds.data.map((dsd , y) => {
          this.barChart.data.datasets[i].data[y] = dsd;
        });
      });
    });
    this.barChart.options.sort = true;
    this.barChart.update();
    this.barChart.options.sort = false;
  }
```

I wrote this on the angular 7 commponent.

I want chart label move with animation. current source code is label change not animation.